# How to receive xml from another webservice with c#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

noob question on web services:

I'm using C#, and need to receive xml from another web service, compare it to data that we have, and determine the differences, and then update the database. What's the best way to deal with this?

Is it that I would receive this as a string right (private void readData(string xmlData)) ? And then then place into a dataset, determine the deltas, and then update the db?

Comment: You need to research web services (or even WCF) as your question reads "how do I do it all?" and *may* be too broad a question for this community. You may also want to review things like serialization

Comment: You've chosen to use xml? Or is that all you can have?

Comment: Yes, and then use [LinqToXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: I can use xml or nested xml.